# java processbuilder run process in the same console

Tags: java, c#, processbuilder

I'm currently writing a program and I have this problem where I want to move the console's cursor to a specific location on the screen.
I quickly found out that this isn't possible in java so I wrote a C# script that would do this for me, but I only can run program in a separate process.

Is there a way to solve this?

Also I'm trying not to use any extra libraries like jline.

Here are some code snippets:

C#

```
using System;

namespace setCursor
{
    public class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt16(args[0]);
            int y = Convert.ToInt16(args[1]);

            Console.SetCursorPosition(x ,y);
        }
    }
}
```

java

```
try
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("setCursor", "0", "0");
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 120; j++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            System.out.print(ContentOnTheScreen[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Terminal / console in recent version of Windows supports [ANSI / VT codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) so you could achieve movement of character position with `System.out.print` if your terminal is compatible. You will be able to tell by running this:

```
public class SetCursor {
    private static String CSI = "\u001b[";
    private static String at(int row, int col) {
        return CSI+row+";"+col+"H";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("HELLO");

        System.out.print(at(1,1)  + "ABCD");
        System.out.print(at(10,5) + "EFGH");

        System.out.println("WORLD");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(at(30,20)  + " Progress: "+i+"%");
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

It will either print the different values around the screen (running from a Windows Terminal Command Prompt), or if VT codes not supported (such as when running via IDE) the output might look strange:

```
HELLO
[1;1HABCD[10;5HEFGHWORLD
...
```

Comment: thanks alot but i'm not able to use the ansi codes on my device... so i will have to wait for another idea on how to solve this...

Comment: What is the device that you are using?

Comment: windows... but my comuter crashed one day and since that day it never functioned normaly